# Remove entry from a table without deleting it from a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've built a small web app in which main view shows a table and administrator has an option to remove a row by deleting it from a database using:

```
*.destroy
```

However I want to keep all the entries in the database but still would like the option for the user to be able to remove the rows from the table and not sure how to go about this.  I was thinking about using two different database tables but wanted to check if there is maybe a simpler way?

Here is my main view:

```
<h1>Student List</h1>

<table class ="Tables">
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Date Submit</th>
<th>Floor Preference</th>
<th></th>
</tr>

<% @students.each do |student|%>
<tr>
<td><%= student.f_name %></td>
<td><%= student.l_name %></td>
<td><%= student.created_at %></td>
<td><%= student.floor_pref %></td>
<td><%= button_to 'Remove', student, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<br />
<%= link_to 'New Student', new_student_path %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can easily do this by creating an extra column in same table with boolean value.
So extra column name can be isActive.
Removed row's isActive would be 0 and rest have 1. 
And when fetching data just put extra check where isActive = 1

Comment: Good solution - side note Rails conventions would recommend a column name of `is_active`

Answer (score 2):

```
rails g migration AddActiveToStudents active:boolean
```

Then in view you can alter the value when they click the "Delete" button

Then put a check after the `.each do |student|`

```
<% if student.active %>
..........display..............
<% end %>
```

Comment: The 'if' doesn't require a 'then'

Comment: that `if ... then` syntax was like VB :-D

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a little more labor intensive, but works for me. My steps are similar but I'll provide more detail because I'm new to programming so I'm going to assume there are others who are new as well:

Assumptions:
- You're working from a single model, views and controller (e.g. Model is Foo)
- You're able to delete a record from the db by clicking on a button that initiates a controller action ("Destroy")
- If you've got associations, destroying a record from the db is problematic to your app.

1. Created a migration for new column named is_active, w/datatype: boolean. Verify that rails created the migration correctly. If not, manually tweak the migration file. Make sure you bundle exec rake db:migrate after ANY change to the db. Restart your server.
2. Edit the destroy action in the controller by setting the is_active variable to false. Boolean evaluates to 'true' or 'false'. For us 'false' will represent a "deleted" row (although it won't be deleted in the database, just hidden from the view. e.g. @foo.is_active = false. Be sure to use the "=" operator, which assigns the value. In the view you'll use a different operator (==). Make sure you do a save after any editing. e.g. @foo.save. Also, comment out any destroy code. e.g. # @foo.destroy

   2a. I also set the is_active value to 'true' in my create action. This may not be necessary but it works for me so far. If you made this adjustment, remember to save. e.g @foo.is_active = true, @foo.save
3. In the view where your results will show, add a conditional statement. I'm looping through my table and painting results. My if statement is after my do loop. If it evaluates to 'false' I'll show a line of text. ELSE, if it evaluates to 'true' I'll show my data. (Generally, on subsequent lines I have: Do Loop, 'False' iF Statement, Else, 'True' Data , End tag).

So, in the "if" statement I'm telling rails that when you're looping thru, if you see a row where the foo.is_active is 'false', show this text. Otherwise (else) show the data between 'else' and 'end'. Notice how the operator in the view is different than the controller. In the view we're checking for equality (==), not assigning a value to (=).

Make sure the variables that you're calling match what you've set in your controller's destroy action. They must be consistent or you'll get error messages. This gave me problems for a few hours before I figured it out. So if you're setting @foo in your controller, then you can only call @foo in your view.

Finally, the view I'm working with is my index but I also but a conditional statement in my show view so my users can toggle is_admin on or off. Using a simple_form_for form, I added the is_admin variable as boolean which shows as a checkbox on my show form. When checked is_admin is 'true' and the row will show. When unchecked is_admin is 'false' and therefore hidden.